# Error comes when using User Defined Case Class in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, count, distinct-values

The result that I am trying to find out is that, I need to find the distinct repos accessed by a particular user, using the inverted index based method in Scala. I have made the required Case Class to extract the data from the input file, and hence made the required RDD and joined on the basis of the required user, but whenver after finding all the repos accessed. When I try to use the distinct and then count function, then I get some error, which I will paste below.

The code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD   
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat 
import java.util.Date
case class LogLine(debug_level: String, timestamp: Date, download_id: String,retrieval_stage: String, rest: String);
val regex = """([^\s]+), ([^\s]+)\+00:00, ([^\s]+) -- ([^\s]+): (.*$)""".r
val rdd = sc.
    textFile("file.txt").
    flatMap ( x => x match {
      case regex(debug_level,dateTime,downloadId,retrievalStage,rest) =>
        val df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss")
        new Some(LogLine(debug_level, df.parse(dateTime.replace("T", ":")), downloadId, retrievalStage, rest))
      case _ => None;
      })
rdd.cache()

val inverted2 = rdd.groupBy(element => element.download_id).cache
val list2 = List[String]("ghtorrent-22")
val user = sc.parallelize(list2).keyBy(x => x)
val poss = inverted2.join(user).flatMap{x => x._2._1}.map(line => line.rest)
```

After this, whenever, I try to run, the next part to evaluate the result, I get the error.

The code and error are as follows:

**Code:**

```
poss.distinct.count
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 59) (LAPTOP-Q81MN7NI executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:4055)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectInputStream.java:3861)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:2043)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1661)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2102)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.readNextItem(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.hasNext(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:538)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1087)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.readNextHashCode(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.$anonfun$new$1(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:315)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.$anonfun$new$1$adapted(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator$$Lambda$3514/0x0000000101065840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.<init>(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.iterator(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2258)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2207)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1079)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2445)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2387)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2376)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:868)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2196)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2217)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2236)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2261)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1253)
  ... 37 elided
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:4055)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.assign(ObjectInputStream.java:3861)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readString(ObjectInputStream.java:2043)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1661)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2102)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream.readValue(Serializer.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.readNextItem(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:514)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$DiskMapIterator.hasNext(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:538)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$22.hasNext(Iterator.scala:1087)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.readNextHashCode(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:335)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.$anonfun$new$1(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:315)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.$anonfun$new$1$adapted(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:313)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator$$Lambda$3514/0x0000000101065840.apply(Unknown Source)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap$ExternalIterator.<init>(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:313)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.iterator(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:287)
  at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:43)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:118)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
```

Comment: You have an _OutOfMemoryError_. What are you memory settings? Did you try increasing?

Comment: I am somewhat new in using Scala, so maybe that's why I am not able to tackle through this problem. Answering your question, I have a 24 GB Ram hardware,but I read somewhere that that doesn't matter as Scala runs on JVM and hence uses the memory from that only. I don't technically know how to increase memory in this case to run the program, Could you guide me on how to use that?

Comment: Also, I tried to run the program iteratively, so that it wouldn't cause any error wrt to memory, but this time I got somewhat different error. The code I used was:
```
var result = List[String]();
for (x <- poss){
    if(!result.contains(x)){
        result = uniqueRepos :+ x;
    }
}
println(result.size);
```
Error:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 16 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 16.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 65) (LAPTOP-... executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Indeed you need to allocate memory to the JVM. There are tons of articles explaining how to do it, nus search for "spark increase memory" for instance.

Comment: Okay, that would be a good approach, but could you refer to me, how would I increase the memory for the process using spylon kernel on jupyter notebook, as most of the articles are for interactive spark shell

Comment: I don't know anything about these tools but pretty sure you can find documentation about it

Comment: Is the `groupBy` needed? Why don't you `rdd.filter(_.download_id == "ghtorrent-22")` instead of joining with a 1-element list? Based on this code `cache` also doesn't seem to be needed. `cache` and `groupBy` are the most likely causes why it goes out of memory.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat instance is created for each row and takes memory. It can be moved outside of "flatMap", like "regex".

Comment: As an aside I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()` will parse the string you got without you specifying any formatter.